# Python/Pandas: Remove rows with outlying values, keeping all columns

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a data-set which contains many numerical and categorical values, and I want to only test for outlying values on the numerical columns and remove rows based on those columns.

I am trying it like this:

```
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

Where it will remove all outlying values in all columns, however of course because I have categorical columns I am met with the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

I know the solution above works because if I limit my `df` to only contain numeric columns it all works fine but I don't want to lose the rest of the information in my dataframe in the process of evaluating outliers from numeric columns.

Comment: @ALollz I've tried doing it like this but it results in an error, I changed my code to: `df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore([df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])])) < 3).all(axis=1)]` so it only looks at numerical columns, but throws the following error: `cannot copy sequence with size 101766 to array axis with dimension 13`. I have 13 numerical columns that is. Could you maybe give me an example on how to do it the way you are saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes) by excluding any *object* (i.e., string) columns.

```
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df.select_dtypes(exclude='object'))) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

To demonstrate using random data (seeded for reproducibility) with a smaller zscore check:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy import stats

LETTERS = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')

np.random.seed(1001)

# DATAFRAME OF 50 COLUMNS
df = pd.DataFrame({'NUM1': np.random.randn(50)*100,
                   'NUM2': np.random.uniform(0,1,50),                   
                   'NUM3': np.random.randint(100, size=50),                                             
                   'CAT1': ["".join(np.random.choice(LETTERS,1)) for _ in range(50)],
                   'CAT2': ["".join(np.random.choice(['pandas', 'r', 'julia', 'sas', 'stata', 'spss'],1)) for _ in range(50)],              
                   'CAT3': ["".join(np.random.choice(['postgres', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'oracle', 'sql server', 'db2'],1)) for _ in range(50)]
                  })

# DATAFRAME OF 11 ROWS
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df.select_dtypes(exclude='object'))) < 1).all(axis=1)]

print(df)   # julia and sql server wins the random draw!
#    CAT1    CAT2        CAT3       NUM1      NUM2  NUM3
# 11    I   julia      sqlite -91.661975  0.443330    73
# 13    I   stata      sqlite  -8.614349  0.668918    69
# 18    H   julia         db2  39.477287  0.624378    56
# 27    B  pandas  sql server -26.400278  0.834240    77
# 29    O    spss    postgres -96.410727  0.748933    45
# 32    Q    spss      sqlite -49.963199  0.731111    70
# 34    R   stata         db2  30.983686  0.772178    62
# 36    B   julia  sql server  72.945459  0.763171    68
# 46    I   julia    postgres   8.454257  0.387944    39
# 48    Y     sas      oracle  85.189272  0.842956    43
# 49    F   stata  sql server -75.488531  0.370730    40
```

Comment: This seems to work really well, I didn't think of doing it in the inverse way to `exclude`. One side question I have, is there any recommendations for choosing a z-score value? I understand that it defines the number of standard deviations apart the data must be and in my case I'm using a value of `3` but would you happen to know any indication as to whether a chosen z-value is necessarily a good value to reduce outlying values?

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I do not believe there is a rule of thumb for outlier criteria. You as the analyst should select with valid reasons. Some remove outliers by very low/high percentiles. It really simply depends on distribution of data, analysis needs, literature practices, etc. Consult co-workers, mentors, classmates, even [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the information and solution! I will definitely look more into the uses of z-score and how I can choose a suitable one for my data-set.